# Pandas DataFrame groupby, transform and count simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working with dataframes in Python, and I would like to group a dataframe by some columns, add a new column informing about the number of rows for each group, and transforming another column values into the max value.

To better explain myself, here is a toy example; I would like to pass from:

```
a   b       c
0   0    True
0   0   False
0   1    True
1   0   False
1   1    True
1   1   False
```

to:

```
a   b   count        c
0   0       2     True
0   1       1     True
1   0       1    False
1   1       2     True
```

The columns to group by are `a` and `b`, the `count` column informs about the number of rows having each combination of `a` and `b`, and the column `e` is been transformed to the max value found for each group (`max(True, False) = True`).

I know I have to use `groupby` and `transform`, but I just can't help finding a correct and elegant solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try: ``df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg(count=('c', 'count'), c = ('c', 'max'))``

Comment: Thanks very much @sammywemmy, it works fine!